# How to use M-<Number> to type a digit?

Tags: emacs

I came across this problem in below situation:
I am trying to enter fourty `0`s. So I pressed:
 <kbd>M-40 0</kbd>. However I ended up with four hundred instances of my next keystroke.
Is there a solution for this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use <kbd>C-u</kbd> to terminate the numeric prefix:

> <kbd>M-40 C-u 0</kbd>

Answer (score 6):

Try this (a C-u terminates the numeric argument):

```
C-u 40 C-u 0
```

Comment: Good answer voted up. (The other working answer was slightly earlier.)